# I am not getting where I am getting wrong

Tags: python-3.x

I have written this program to find the maximum of a 1 dimensional array. But, when I entered 3,7,etc.. as number of elements, I am getting list index out of range error. Please help me to solve this query.

```
t = list(map(int, input().split()))
t = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
def peakf(t):
    n=len(t)//2
    if(len(t)==2):
      if(t[0]>t[n]):
          return(t[0])
      else:
          return(t[1])
    else:
      if(t[n-1]>t[n]):
        return(peakf(t[:n]))
      elif(t[n+1]>t[n]):
        return(peakf(t[n+1:]))
      else:
        return(t[n])
print(peakf(t))
```

Comment: you are using recursion with no base case add the base case it will work

Comment: @RajuKomati Please write the whole code. I am not getting what you are trying to say

Comment: Why don't you handle the case of ``len(t) == 1``?

Comment: It seems your approach will only work if the list is sorted already. In which case you might just as well unconditionally ``return t[-1]``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using `n+1` in else condition that is causing index out of range error. use `peakf(t[n:])` it will work.

```
t = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
def peakf(t):
    n=len(t)//2
    if(len(t)==2):
      if(t[0]>t[n]):
          return(t[0])
      else:
          return(t[1])
    else:
      if(t[n-1]>t[n]):
        return(peakf(t[:n]))
      elif(t[n+1]>t[n]):
        return(peakf(t[n:]))
      else:
        return(t[n])
print(peakf(t))
```

Comment: I only solved the error in @Aziz Lokhandwala code. as per logic  it will work only for sorted arrays.

Answer (score 1):

If all you are trying to do is find the largest value in an array, why not use something much simpler like the following:

```py
t = [10,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
def peakf(vals):
    max = -999999999999
    for val in vals:
        if val > max:
            max = val
    return max
print(peakf(t))
```

It simply loops over every value in the array and checkers it against the current largest value, if it is larger, then the current largest value becomes that value, otherwise it continues.

An even easier way to do this would be to use the `max()` function.